# Input text value in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

This Code note note working Please help. I try to know more about Jquery, Ajax Get & Post. Can use the code in PhoneGap App?

I use this tutorial - https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    var a= $("#test1").val();
    var b= $("#test2").val();

        $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
        {
          name: a,
          city: b
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
 <p>F Name: <input type="text" id="test1" value="Mickey Mouse"></p>

<p>S Name: <input type="text" id="test2" value="Mickey Mouse"></p>


<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>
```

But this change had worked

```
 var a= "FName";
    var b= "SName";
```

Comment: I would start with correcting the syntax errors: `$("#test1").val());` there is a parenthesis too much at the end

Comment: Secondly, what does the receiving server-side code look like?

Comment: They use a server script for receive and send data who's called `demo_test_post.asp` if you haven't a server side script who can receive and return your data it will never work localy :-)

Comment: First I want to correct this code. Just a experiment in PhoneGap

Comment: >>>I would start with correcting the syntax errors: $("#test1").val()); <<< Thanks empiric

Comment: Can I use in PhoneGap App.